# Express route parameter clarification

Tags: express

I'm setting up Express routes, and I'd like a little clarification on how to use parameters correctly. At first, I tried this, thinking that as long as the parameter I passed through was called either `id` or `english`, the router would know which route to choose. This didn't work correctly:

```js
myRoute.route('/nouns/:id').get((req, res) => {
  ...
})

myRoute.route('/nouns/:english').get((req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

I've changed the routes to this, which works:

```js
myRoute.route('/nouns/id/:id').get((req, res) => {
  ...
})

myRoute.route('/nouns/english/:english').get((req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

Is this the correct syntax? I'm asking because it seems redundant to have the parameter name twice (`id/:id`, `english/:english`)?

Comment: Do you actually _want_ a parameter in the route? What requests are you expecting this to handle?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yep, I want to pass a parameter (english or id), so I can then query my mongo db based on that attribute

Comment: Are they the only two options? And why would the variable need to have the same name as the value?

Comment: They're the only two routes I have that I need to pass parameters. For your second question, I believe that is what I'm trying to clarify. I think in fact, it doesn't matter, but there's no other logical name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way parameters work is so that you can have dynamic routes. See the example:

```
Route: /nouns/id
Matches: /nouns/id

Route: /nouns/english
Matches: /nouns/english

Route: /nouns/:id
Matches: /nouns/a, /nouns/b, /nouns/c, /nouns/foobar, etc...
```

So with a parameter, it means that anything could be there, and it also lets you get the value of it. If you just want a certain route, then there is no need for a parameter.

See: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

---

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. So, if I need two routes, so that I can query my mongo db based on either the ``id`` or ``english`` attributes, I can use my examples, and the fact that ``id/:id`` is duplicated is irrelevant

Comment: Pretty much if you need something like `/nouns/id/theidhere` to work.